# my android app doesn't parse the data generated by php

Tags: php, json

I generate the data using php script and it shows a json data,
I have my android app that parse that data.
When i open that link it doesn't parse that data.
but when I copy the script generated output to a file with .json extension than my app is able to parse the data.
Sorry for my English.
And thanks in advance.
I am newbie to json.
Here is my php code which generate json data.

```
$jsonresponse = array("members"=>array());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $row['firstname'] = ucfirst(strtolower($row['firstname']));
    $row['surname'] = ucfirst(strtolower($row['surname']));
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['firstname']." ".$row['surname'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $jsonrow = array(
        "id"=>$id,
        "name"=>$name,
        "city"=>$city
    );

    array_push($jsonresponse["members"],$jsonrow);
}

echo json_encode($jsonresponse);
```

Output

```
{"members":[{"id":"1","name":"Sarvagna Mehta","city":"Ahmedabad"}]}
```

No, need to change anything in android code.
Just solved my problem.

Comment: Do you mind showing your output at least?

Comment: Have you tried setting the header of the response? Place `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before your `echo`.

Comment: Yes, I already place header just after <?php.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by 'doesn't parse that data'? What is the result of parsing? What errors do you get?

Comment: When i copy this output to result.json and copy to my server and access it from my android activity like http://server.com/search/result.json it display that data in listview. But When the same in http://server.com/search/index.php , my android activity shows blank screen.

Comment: Well, we can't help you here. It's not a PHP problem. Consider retagging the question for android.

Comment: show your parsing code...

Comment: But my android app working well, it parse the same data from result.json, and only problem is parsing from index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,
I forgot to add charset=utf-8 to my PHP script.
Thanks all.

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```